# Serializing inherited types in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem when serializing inherited objects in Web API.

```
[DataContract] 
public class Item{
     [DataMember]
     public int ID{get; set;}
     [DataMember]
     public string Name{get; set;} }

[DataContract] 
public class SitecoreItem : Item{
     [DataMember]     
     public DbType SitecoreInstance{get; set;} }
```

I am trying to return the above mentioned SitecoreItem from WebAPI, but it screams serialization errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no different than serialization in WCF. Just use `KnownType`

```
[DataContract] 
[KnownType(typeof(SitecoreItem))]
public class Item{
     [DataMember]
     public int ID{get; set;}
     [DataMember]
     public string Name{get; set;} }

[DataContract] 
public class SitecoreItem : Item{
     [DataMember]     
     public DbType SitecoreInstance{get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: What if we don't have access to the code of `Item`? For example, `Item` is in a third-party library. How could we put `KnownType` above it?