# Restful not GET subclass C#

Tags: c#, rest, subclass

my problem is:

```
class A
{
  public string id {get;set;}
  public string name {get;set;}
}

class B:A
{
  public string reg_id {get;set;}
}
```

When I debug I see class B have: [+base] [+reg_id] attribute.

But when I GET class B from Restful only have two attribute of class A (id, name) not include reg_id.
Thanks for Regards !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996459/serializing-inherited-types-in-asp-net-web-api+

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  What do you mean by getting class B from restful?  Are you using JSON.NET? XML?

Comment: In GET method I return `IENumrable<[Class B]>` and in `WebApiConfig` i use `JsonFormatter`

Comment: @Habib I'm using Restful

Comment: Thank you Habib, I fixed by add [DataContact]